# When use module to register controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have two functional code to register controller with Angular.

**The first code is:**

*In app.js:*

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['...']);
app.config(...

    $stateProvider
    .state('first', { 
         url: '/first', 
         templateUrl: 'first.html', 
         controller: 'myController1'
    }).state('second', { 
         url: '/second', 
         templateUrl: 'second.html', 
         controller: 'myController2'
    });
);
```

*In myControllers.js*

```
app.controller('myController1', function(){
      ...
});

app.controller('myController2', function(){
      ...
});
```

**The second code is:**

*In app.js:*

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['...', 'myControllers']);
app.config(...

    $stateProvider
    .state('first', { 
         url: '/first', 
         templateUrl: 'first.html', 
         controller: 'myController1'
    }).state('second', { 
         url: '/second', 
         templateUrl: 'second.html', 
         controller: 'myController2'
    });
);
```

*In myControllers.js*

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('myController1', function(){
      ...
});

myControllers.controller('myController2', function(){
      ...
});
```

What is the best solution ? why use module to contain several controllers ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A module in Angular is a way to logically package up related code into chunks.  These chunks can be composed later (think 3rd party library in other languages).

This is typically how you include external Angular code (from github etc) into your project.  The external project creates a module for you to use as a module dependency.  This is the `angular.module('myApp', ['myDependency'])` way.

This is an optional feature, but can be useful on large (or naturally segregated) projects.

If you don't have a need for a module.  I'd suggest you use the simpler (first) solution.

[Module Documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)